# Как получить список шаблонов процесса в TFS?

Tags: c#, tfs

Мне нужно получить список шаблонов процесса в TFS, чтобы в дальнейшем создавать свои шаблоны процессов. Как получить этот интерфейс?

```
IProcessTemplate processTemplate;
```

Comment: Исправил вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я всегда использую клиента к рабочим элементам для получения сервиса:

```
WorkItemStore _wistore = new WorkItemStore("http://server_name:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection");
IProcessTemplates _templates = _wistore.TeamProjectCollection.GetService<IProcessTemplates>();

foreach (TemplateHeader _tmpl in _templates.TemplateHeaders())
   Console.WriteLine("Process template: ID - {0}; Name - {1}; State - {2}\n{3}", _tmpl.TemplateId, _tmpl.Name, _tmpl.State, _tmpl.Description);
```

Тут есть список функций сервиса: https://loicbaumann.fr/en/2009/04/02/what-you-need-to-know-to-use-the-process-template-api/

Comment: Спасибо, у меня есть ещё вопрос: "Могу ли я получив шаблон изменить его элементы и т.д. под свои нужды?"

Comment: Через код я такого не делал.Но думаю (исходя из ссылки), что получить процесс можно GetTemplateData и потом распаковать зип. Далее нужно поправить xml-воркитемы в папке "WorkItem Tracking\TypeDefinitions" [On-premises XML process model](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/on-premises-xml-process-model?view=azure-devops-2019). Потом запаковать и отправить обратно через AddUpdateTemplate.